# What is the default noise parameters in sensor inputs in robot_localization?

Tags: navigation, ekf, robot-localization, ekf-localization-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my yaml parameter file I have not specified any initial noise or process noise for my two sensors. What default noise values will the extended Kalman filter use on these inputs? I have tried to find the default values in the documentation http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/robot_localization/html/index.html and the source code https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization without success.

In the documentation it states: Missing covariances. If you have configured a given sensor to fuse a given variable into the state estimation node, then the variance for that value (i.e., the covariance matrix value at position (i,i), where i is the index of that variable) should not be 0. If a 0 variance value is encountered for a variable that is being fused, the state estimation nodes will add a small epsilon value (1e−6) to that value. A better solution is for users to set covariances appropriately.

Does this mean that all the noise is set to a small epsilon value (1e−6)? And does this apply for both process and initial noise? Or does it mean that if a value is set to 0 a small epsilon value (1e−6) will be added to that 0?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353624/what-is-the-default-noise-parameters-in-sensor-inputs-in-robot_localization?/) by [DanielRobotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/34746/danielrobotics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2020-05-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the variance in the covariance matrix for a measurement is smaller than 1e-9 it will set it to 1e-9.

[In the source code](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/3f8118496b9c1e065fde55533e43dc8d0fd381a2/src/ekf.cpp#L138)

Also regarding the process noise this is the default values:

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [bob-ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/45543/bob-ros/) with karma: 525 on 2020-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DanielRobotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/34746/danielrobotics/) on 2020-06-01**:
So If I am not defined them it the yaml file I will get the values above?

**Comment by [bob-ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/45543/bob-ros/) on 2020-06-01**:
That is correct.